# How can I add a criteria to a grails criteria to limit results based on a filtered association?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria-api

In my old java code I could do this to "join" another table in a hibernate query and filter results based on it.

```
 final Criteria brokerageCriteria = userCriteria.createCriteria("brokerage");
            if (queryDto.getBrokerageID() != null) {
                brokerageCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", queryDto.getBrokerageID()));
            }
```

In this example it would filter users who are a member of a specific brokerage only (each user has one brokerage).

As you can see I can easily join other tables that are associated in the hibernate mappings by calling criteria.createCriteria(String associationName).  Is there anything similar to this in grails?  I am trying to build a general purpose JSON-to-criteria web api for our internal developers to search various tables, page through data, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the scenario, here is the `domain` classes and `criteria` query

```
//Domain User
class User{
    //each user has one brokerage
    static hasOne = [brokerage: Brokerage]
}

//Domain Brokerage
class Brokerage{
    //Optional
    //static belongsTo = [user: User]
}

//Criteria Query
def user = User.createCriteria().get{
    brokerage{
       idEq(queryDto.getBrokerageID())
    }
}
```

or You can also use the non-DSL way

```
def user = User.createCriteria().get{
       eq('brokerage.id', queryDto.getBrokerageID())
}
```

Joining associated tables in easier in case of `criteria` in grails because it uses DSLs(domain specific language). In the above example, only by providing the association in the criteria as `brokerage{}` an INNER JOIN is done on `User` and `Brokerage` based on `brokerageId`.

The beauty of `Criteria` in grails is that you can dynamically handle your query. For example, if a `User` has one `Brokerage` and one `Mortgage` and many `Lien`s, and you want to get an `User` from the system if any of the `brokerageId`, `mortgageId`, `lienId` is provided in the JSON. The above criteria can be effectively enhanced as

```
def user = User.createCriteria().get{
      if(queryDto.getBrokerageID() != null){
          brokerage{
             idEq(queryDto.getBrokerageID())
          }
      } else if(queryDto.getMortgageID() != null){
          mortgage{
             idEq(queryDto.getMortgageID())
          }
      } else if(queryDto.getLienID() != null){
          liens{
             idEq(queryDto.getLienID())
          }
      }
   }
```

`User` domain would look like

```
class User{
        //each user has one brokerage and one mortgage
        static hasOne = [brokerage: Brokerage, mortgage: Mortgage]
        static hasMany = [liens: Lien] //many Liens
    }
```