# Dynamically generating SQL queries in Grails

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm, dynamic-queries

We have a search page on a grails application.  This page needs to be able to dynamically  build queries based on a number of properties.

For example:

- "find users with email like bob.smith@%"
- "find users with email equal "john.smith@gmail.com"
- "find users who are a member of group x"
- "find user with id 42"
- "find user with name like "Jason P%"

If this were a Java application I would use the hibernate criteria API.  One problem with the criteria API is it makes arbitrary joins impossible.

So is there a way to dynamically build queries like this?  If the criteria API in GORM can be dynamically modified that could work, or I could use a totally different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452345/how-can-i-add-a-criteria-to-a-grails-criteria-to-limit-results-based-on-a-filter/16452544#16452544) from you was answered by @dmahapatro few months back. Your present scenario would look something like:

```
def user = User.createCriteria().list{
      if(params.email != null){
          or{
             eq('email', params.email)
             iLike('email', "%${params.email}%")
          }
      } else if(params.id != null){
          idEq(params.id)
      } else if(params.name != null){
          eq('name', params.name)
      } else if(params.memberOf != null){ //This can be optimized
         groups{
            eq('name', params.memberOf)
         }
      }
   }
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: How could I dynamically join other entities/tables to this query?

Comment: @Benju I already did, assuming `groups` is an association to User. It will be convenient if you show some domains to sample against. :)